# How can I extract only the points-value from an SVG file using JavaScript?

Tags: string, svg

How can I read a specific string (points="*") from an SVG-file in Javascript?
This is how the SVG-file looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     x="0px" y="0px" width="1920px" height="1080px" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    
    <polygon fill-rule="evenodd" points="895.282,487.399 895.282,467.851 944.553,487.934 993.707,447.428 993.997,467.014 
        944.884,508.359 895.282,487.399     "/>
</g>
</svg>
```

I managed to read the entire file into a JS-var using this:

```
<!-- SVG READING TEST -->
    <object data="svg/polygonised.svg" type="image/svg+xml"
         id="svg" width="100%" height="100%"></object>

        <script>
            var a = document.getElementById("svg");

            a.addEventListener("load",function(){

                // get the inner DOM of the svg
                var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
                
                // get the inner element by id
                var polys = svgDoc.getElementsByTagName("polygon");
        console.log(polys);
                
        // get the value of points THIS DOES NOT WORK :(
        var points = polys[0].points;
        console.log(points);
```

I don´t know how to extract only the points from the svg?!

If I add manually an ID to the SVG it works, but unfortunately these SVG´s are created automatically and do not contain an ID. Otherwise this works and will deliver only the points:

```
<!-- SVG READING TEST -->
    <object data="svg/polygonised.svg" type="image/svg+xml"
         id="svg" width="100%" height="100%"></object>

        <script>
            var a = document.getElementById("svg");

            a.addEventListener("load",function(){

                // get the inner DOM of the svg
                var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
                
                // get the inner element by id
                var id = svgDoc.getElementById("test");
                console.log(id);
                
        // get the value of points
        var points = id.getAttribute("points");
        console.log(points);
```

The main goal is to automatically read hundreds or even thousands of SVGs, extract only the points-value and transfer those into a new var.

Unfortunately, I am an absolute beginner and have been struggling with this problem for days without finding a solution. Any help or even just pointing into the right direction would be really appreciated :-)

Comment: What does "THIS DOES NOT WORK" mean? What's wrong with what it returns?

Comment: Both example actually work.  `polygon.points`  returns a  SVGPointList containing point objects, whereas  `polygon.getAttribute('points')` will return just the attribute value as string (quite likely you'll need to convert it to an array of coordinates). Apart from this, please make sure your scripts/function are properly closed - your example is missing closing barckets and a closing script tag

Comment: You don't need an ID, use ``querySelector`` and/or ``querySelectorAll``. ``document.querySelectorAll("svg [points]").forEach(polygon =>console.log(polygon.getAttribute("points")))``

Comment: Thanks a LOT for your help, guys!
I actually got it working with 
var points = polygon[0].points;
which put all point-values into an array "points". Now I can easily access this array with a for-loop. Thx again :D